# Testing the Test Data from files(xml,json,csv,txt) dynamically using Junit and Mockito in a gradle project

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I am currently aligned to a task which is related to Junit and mockito.

**Current Status:**
One of my collegue has develop some test cases using Junit , Mockito and Gradle. Now while developing the code what he has done while testing the conditions he had passed the values as hardcoded but now there is a new Change Request(CR)

**Assumption :**
We are assuming all the hard-coded values will be store inside some resource folder.Now this Resource folder would contain any type of file because data could be of Json, Xml , CSv, txt or anything.

**Requirement:**
We wanted to read this data from the file which could be of any type(Json, Xml , CSV, txt) parse it and then we need to add this data using annotations without using getter setter there in place where we are using the hard-coded values just to hide the hard-coded values and then the run the test cases using dynamic values?

What must be done to Read data from the file , parse that data as per the type of data and then using annotations get the values rather using getter setter?

Comment: If I wanted to read test data from JSON or XML rather than csv file what annotations can be used with JSON or XML to read the data and then parse it and then test that using junit?

Answer (score 1):

In JUnit5 you can run parameterized tests with [csv source](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests-sources-CsvSource). You cn see an example with inline csv values:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.CsvSource;

class PriceCalculatorTest {

  PriceCalculator classUnderTest;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() throws Exception {
    classUnderTest = new PriceCalculator();
  }

  @ParameterizedTest
  @CsvSource({"0.0, 13", "5.0, 14", "5.0,26", "15.0,27", "15.0,64", "10.0,65"})
  void testGetPrice(double expected, int age) {
    assertEquals(expected, classUnderTest.getPrice(age), 0.01D);
  }
}
```

If you want to use an external data file there is a slightly different syntax for that:

```
@CsvFileSource(resources = "/two-column.csv", numLinesToSkip = 1)
```

This assumes you are using a csv file with headers in the first line. If you want to use another file format, you need to implement your own `ArgumentsProvider`.